# How to do transfer material from one warehouse to other warehouse in SAP MM Module?

Tags: transfer, sap-erp

I am making application in SAP MM. How to do transfer material from one warehouse to other warehouse in SAP MM Module?

please share code snippet or useful link, which is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried BAPI_GOODSMOVEMENT_CREATE ?  It should do what you want.